# If you conquer a holy city do you take "ownership" of that religion?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I've conquered a city that was the holy city for one of the religions.  I didn't manage to found a religion myself.

**Does this mean I own that religion and can upgrade it and do whatever else the owner of a religion can do?**

The original Civ isn't wiped out, by the way, I just took a few of their cities including their capital and holy city.

Comment: PS - can you buy great prophets with faith (I'm sure I've done that before), and if so is that related to owning the religion?

Comment: Buying Great Prophets with Faith is unrelated to owning a religion; it's just a factor of earning enough Faith to make the purchase.

Comment: I think it's possible to wipe out the religion by sending your on inquisitor and wipe it. May be handy if your rival has been converting too many of your cities directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Even if you wipe out the civ, it is still not your religion.

The holy city (and other cities) will continue to spread that religion and you will gain the benefits of any pantheon or follower beliefs in it but it is still not your religion. You will not be able to benefit from its founder beliefs or add to that religion through enhancing or reformation.

If you buy missionaries or great prophets from that city, they will be of and will spread that religion.

Comment: Last sentence - is this true in all cases? I seem to recall the Iroquois sending a Great Prophet and religion-bombing my holy city into another religion, and when I bought an Inquisitor to try to remove it, it was of the other religion since the new religion had a (temporary) majority.

Comment: @AdamV AFAIK your inquisitor would be the one from the majority. So that case, it's a little too late. I was in a Venice game where Pacal did that, infected the cities that I trade with, making it very difficult for me to convert back to my religion in a short term. I just didn't have an inquisitor on hand with my religion to wipe it off, or to kill his holy city (I had captured it).